# Invalid conversion from BaseClass* to DerivedClass*

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11

I'm trying to use the factory method to return a derived class but the return type is the base class type. From my understanding I thought inheritance would allow me to do this, obviously I am wrong.

WeightExercise and CardioExercise are both derived from Exercise.

I could cast the object but I thought my design would mean I don't have to do that. Can  someone point out my mistake please?

Main

```
ExerciseFactory ExerciseFactoryObj;
WeightExercise *WeightExerciseObj = ExerciseFactoryObj.createExercise(menuselection);
```

Factory Class

```
class ExerciseFactory
{
public:
ExerciseFactory();
~ExerciseFactory();
Exercise* createExercise(int exercisetype);


private:
static WeightExercise* createWeightExercise() { return new WeightExercise(); }
static CardioExercise* createCardioExercise() { return new CardioExercise(); }
};
```

Factory Implementation

```
Exercise* ExerciseFactory::createExercise(int exercisetype)
{
if ( 1 == exercisetype )
{
    return this->createWeightExercise();
}
else if ( 2 == exercisetype )
{
    return this->createCardioExercise();
}
else
{
    cout << "Error: No exercise type match" << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: You are assigning to return value to the derived class. you have to assign it to a BaseClass *

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can assign a Derived class returned from the factory to the base class one :

```
ExerciseFactory ExerciseFactoryObj;
Exercice *WeightExerciseObj = ExerciseFactoryObj.createExercise(menuselection);
```

**Edited:**

If you really need to access WeightExerciceObject element use :

```
WeightExerciceObject * weight = dynamic_cast<WeightExerciceObject *>(ExerciseFactoryObj.createExercise(menuselection));
```

this will return NULL if the class is not the exact one. You need to check against NULL.

Comment: Thank you. Surely this will mean I won't be able to access the members of WeightExercise though?

Comment: If you find yourself doing a lot of those dynamic_cast you might want to review the design of the base class.

Comment: Looks like that is the case. I assume this is why I should use an interface rather than a base class?

Comment: No in this case Interface or BaseClass is the same. See if the Derived classes can have all the same method . However dynamic_cast is sometimes needed that's why it is there :-)

Comment: Do forget to click Accept if the answer solved your question :)

Answer (score 1):

In the main method, this:

```
WeightExercise *WeightExerciseObj = ExerciseFactoryObj.createExercise(menuselection);
```

should be this

```
Exercise *WeightExerciseObj = ExerciseFactoryObj.createExercise(menuselection);
```

You can't use WeightExercise, because you don't know what specific type of exercise is being returned, it might be a CardioExercise or a WeightExercise, or some other future type you aren't yet aware of.